# Using the results of a RESTful web service as data in Crystal Reports

Tags: web-services, rest, crystal-reports, metadata

In our current project, we want to use data from a RESTful web service to populate a Crystal Report. The service is RESTful and does not expose metadata. Is it possible to bind a Crystal report to such a web serve?

I'm currently working from the assumption that I will need to build some kind of adapter if I want this scenario to work. Am I reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Should work fine, but you'll need a schema.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "XML and Web Services" data source?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The schema is a requirement.

[image]

[image]

If you post a dummy GET service, it would be easy to test.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something incorrect, but this does not appear to be working for me.